# Meu signed apk não executa em meu celular

Tags: java, android, apk

Finalizei um pequeno aplicativo que salva anotações e estou tentando gerar o signed apk, porém o mesmo não funciona no meu celular.

- Já testei gerando um signed apk a partir de um novo projeto com apenas uma blank activity e o mesmo funcionou normalmente em meu celular.
- Refiz o processo de gerar o signed apk umas 10x e nenhuma delas funcionou.
- Meu aplicativo funciona normalmente no emulador pelo Android Studio(o que me deixa sem entender o problema de não funcionar em meu celular).

Meu pequeno projeto está no github e tem apenas 2 activity's, ou seja, não é complexo...

Agradeceria se alguém pudesse dar uma olhada para mim...(lembrando que já pesquisei muito na internet e tentei várias opções).
desde já obrigado!

link do projeto no github: https://github.com/LucasBaltazar/Simple-Notes

baixem e tentem gerar o signed apk para verem, aguardo respostas!

**Edição**

Esse projeto dá este erro:

> 01-07 16:35:55.009  16335-16335/com.lbttecnology.notes
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lbttecnology.notes/com.lbttecnology.notes.NotesActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add header view to list --
>   setAdapter has already been called.
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2446)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5434)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:834)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot add header view to list -- setAdapter has already been called.
>                   at android.widget.ListView.addHeaderView(ListView.java:261)
>                   at android.widget.ListView.addHeaderView(ListView.java:290)
>                   at com.lbttecnology.notes.NotesActivity.onCreate(NotesActivity.java:53)
>                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
>                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1146)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2446)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
>                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5434)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:834)
>                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Qual o seu `android:targetSdkVersion`? E qual a versão do seu Android no celular?

Comment: celular: 4.1.2(16) // projeto: minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21

Comment: Mas ele instala no seu celular? O que acontece ao certo?

Comment: Ele instala normalmente, porém, quando eu clico no ícone dele para executar o aplicativo ele me dá a seguinte mensagem: "O Notes parou"

Comment: Se vc puder baixar o projeto no github e olhar ai em sua máquina, acredito que talvez vc saiba resolver...

Comment: Alterei a pergunta com o erro gerado pelo seu aplicativo. Tem ai qualquer problema. Não usa o logcat você para testar?

Comment: Então, no meu emulador não gera erro..já verifiquei o problema que vc postou, corrigi, gerei o apk e instalei no meu celular e rodou normalmente.

Comment: Antes de mais nada, muito obrigado, sou muito grato por sua ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu código você possui estas duas linhas

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
getListView().addHeaderView(menu);
```

Onde primeiro você seta o adapter e depois adiciona o Header, isso só funciona desta forma a partir do Android KitKat, antes dele era obrigatório definir o Header antes de setar o adapter

O que deve estar acontecendo com você é que o emulador está usando uma imagem do Android KitKat ou o Lollipop, onde isso funciona, enquanto no seu celular provavelmente você tem uma versão anterior do Android e ele não permite que se faça isso.

Talvez simplesmente invertendo a ordem destas duas linhas resolva o seu problema.

Comment: Valeu cara, o Jorge B. já tinha resolvido meu problema, mas agradeço msm assim a atenção! Darei joinha na sua respostas para as próximas pessoas que tiverem esse mesmo problema possam resolvê-lo.